# Django Connection to MySQL RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant

Tags: django, apache, centos, python-3.6, mod-wsgi

I have configured the sample Django application to be on virtualenv, with apache and mod_wsgi. This application will be running on a centos server.

However, when I have changed my settings.py file to the mysql setting, I have received a 500 Internal error.

Logs

```
[wsgi:error] [pid 11556]  Traceback (most recent call last):  
[wsgi:error] [pid 11556]    File "/var/www/django/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py", line 35, in <module>.  
[wsgi:error] [pid 11556]      application = get_wsgi_application().  
[wsgi:error] [pid 11556]    File "/var/www/django/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application.   
[wsgi:error] [pid 11556]      django.setup(set_prefix=False).   
[wsgi:error] [pid 11556]    File "/var/www/django/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
[wsgi:error] [pid 11556]      apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS).   
[wsgi:error] [pid 11556]    File "/var/www/django/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 81, in populate   
[wsgi:error] [pid 11556]      raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")   
[wsgi:error] [pid 11556]  RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

settings.py

```
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'test',
        'USER': 'test_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password_test',
        'HOST': '192.168.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

Running the following command on the server itself does not show any errors

```
python manage.py runserver
```

However, when it's deployed via mod_wsgi, the above error is shown.

Help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Go back and find the very first error after the process restarted and when Django application was first being loaded. That error you show is a subsequent error and not the source of the problem. Only the first error shows the actual problem.